# quickly change categroies shown in eclipse overview ruler

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am wondering if there is a quick way to toggle what is shown on the overview bar temporarily (errors, warnings, todos).

Sometimes I try to see where in my code something occures, however the overview ruler is cluttered with all the other markers, so its hard to see. Is there a quick way to toggle what is shown without going through the options every time?

Comment: try [this workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39781211/1422630)