# Changing the priority of markers in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, icons

When I set a break point on a row which already has a marker(The value of the local variable is not used) on it, I cannot see the break point marker; because the yellow lamp marker covers the break point marker.

Is it possible to change the priority of the markers so that the break point sits on top of the lamp marker?

[image]

Comment: Related question but no answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052576/quickly-change-categroies-shown-in-eclipse-overview-ruler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as @Mena answer is ok, as he sais...

> Use at your own risk :)

This can be dangerous in a big project.

---

To avoid problems with hided warnings due configurations, what I usually do is:

- Leave config as is, to see warnings.
- Remove all **really unnecessary** lines causing warnings
- Add an annotation to method still having warnings but needing breakpoint at same line. 
   *You can annotate class if necessary when massive warnings or breakpoints needed.*

  ```
  @SuppressWarning("unused") 
  public void yourMethod() {
  }
  ```

This will allow you to handle warnings individually and see breakpoints when necessary.

Comment: Thank all of you for your answers. I think if I really want to change the priority, I would have to modify the source code of eclipse, which is not something I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I find that incredibly annoying too.

The only solution I've found is to go to the Java editor preferences, and disable the checkbox "Report problems as you type".

This will not change the priority, it will disable the hint and only show the breakpoint.

Here's a picture to illustrate:

[image]

Use at your own risk :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion :)

Comment: @lyen you're welcome. I wish I had a better "solution".

Comment: check mine! finally... finally... :), happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Finally a TRUE relief after years of a so annoying and tiny thing:

1) go to your eclipse install path and look for all files (filename) that contain the word "warn" and are of the format .gif or .png (because they contain transparency data), here there were 5 files whose icon/image matched, most were named as: quickfix_warning_obj.gif (or.png)

2) rename all of them to *.DISABLED like "quickfix_warning_obj.gif.DISABLED", and as soon you restart eclipse, this will force it to restore the right one as soon you open an editor that uses it and has some warning on it.

3) having detected the right file, replace it with one of identical size (width and height in pixels), I would like to suggest this image I just created, so simple and not annoying at all and still is useful!
[image: quickfix_warning_obj.gif]

4) restart eclipse again and clap with a smiling face!

PS.: you can try to just replace this file also, that was the right one here for Eclipse Luna:
`$ECLIPSE_INSTALL_PATH/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/478/0/.cp/icons/full/obj16/quickfix_warning_obj.gif`

Obs.:

- Of course you can replace all of them that look the same, change other annoying icons and so on, and experiment with your own gif/png size and image, just that these steps is what worked perfectly here.
- The image I supplied is almost invisible some times, but they were never really useful to me as I let the code with warning become underlined as a highlight. A better image is welcome :)
- And, of course, this is a workaround, like a theme change, that does not involve any coding/recompiling of eclipse, therefore the priority is not changed at all, but the results are good enough to me at least.

EDIT: here one for the search results: `searchm_obj.gif` [image: searchm_obj.gif] at `configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/331/0/.cp/icons/full/obj16/searchm_obj.gif` on Luna